# include external css files in nodejs

Tags: css, node.js, express, sass, ejs

I want to include external css file in node.js ejs.

I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('/view'))
```

and included css like this way in ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="materialize.scss">
```

> It always gives this error

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/static/materialize.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile first the scss into css. The browser doen't understand the scss code.

```
npm install --save scss
sass static/materialize.scss static/css/materialize.css
```

Then add the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/materialize.css">
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: sass static/materialize.scss:static/css/materialize.css where should i write this

Comment: that's a command, do it in console. After you installed saas.

Comment: I update the post, if it doen't work, have a look [here](https://sass-lang.com/install) to the command line section.